# Trying to do a simple model of a bank account for school and the function get_balance yields an error

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

After i run the code through python 3 I get this error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is my code...

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, number, name, balance):
            self.number = number
            self.name = name
            self.balance = int(balance)

    def get_balance(self):
            return self.balance()

    def deposit(self, amount):
            self.balance += amount
            return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance
def test():
    print('Accounts:')
    a1 = Account(123, 'Scott', 10)
    a1 = Account(124, 'Donald T.', 1000000)

    print('Testing get_balance:')
    print(a1.get_balance())
    print(a2.get_balance())

    print('Testing deposit:')
    a1.deposit(100)
    a2.deposit(50)
    print(a1.get_balance())
    print(a2.get_balance())

    print('Testing withdraw:')
    a1.withdraw(100)
    a2.withdraw(50)
    print(a1.get_balance())
    print(a2.get_balance())
```

I run python and i enter this...

```
>>>import bank
>>>bank.test()
```

Afterwords, this is printed

```
Accounts:
Testing get_balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/scottb0898/CSE1010/HW5/bank.py", line 23, in test
    print(a1.get_balance())
  File "/home/scottb0898/CSE1010/HW5/bank.py", line 9, in get_balance
    return self.balance()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

I'm sure it's a very simple fix, but I just can't figure out what's wrong.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.balance` is only a variable, not a function.  It doesn't need to be called, just change `get_balance` to

```
def get_balance(self):
    return self.balance
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace line 9 with:

```
return self.balance
```

`self.balance` is a number, not a function, thus generating an error when you try to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
def get_balance(self):
        return self.balance #remove '()'
```

and

```
a2 = Account(124, 'Donald T.', 1000000) #a2 instead a1
```

Answer (score 0):

there are mistakes in your code. In get_balance() function you are returning self.balance() where there should be self.balance, only. Also, you are creating two objects inside test of same name 'a1'.